# How do I fast make a list of 1~100?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I was a python beginner, I could create a multiple lines for loop that make a list of 1~100:

```
a=[]
for i in range(1,101):
    a.append(i)
```

When I knew how to write a single line for loop, I could simply my code.

```
a=[ _ for _ in range(1,101)]
```

When I review python document and relearn python in detail now, I find `range()` built-in function it can directly make a list, but I look no one doing this. Why?

```
a=range(1,101)
```

Comment: `a=[i for i in range(1,101)]`

Comment: `_` is a throwaway variable.

Comment: I use python2, not python3.

Comment: Where do you see nobody doing this?

Comment: If you haven't seen people doing this, it's because you haven't seen people need to do it, or you've been looking at the code of people who don't know Python well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### In Python 2.x

If you want to create a list of numbers from 1 to 100, you simply do:

```
range(1, 101)
```

#### In Python 3.x

`range()` no longer returns a list, but instead returns a generator. We can easily convert that into a list though.

```
list(range(1, 101))
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I review python document and relearn python in detail now, I find
>   range() built-in function it can directly make a list, but I look no
>   one doing this.

Depends, if you are using Python 2.X it does but for Python 3.X it produces a range object which should be iterated upon to create a list if you need to.

But in any case for all practical purpose extending a range object as a List comprehension is useless and have an unnecessary memory hogging.